# How to fix verbose unittest output with subtests?

Tags: python-unittest

When using unittest with subtests and verbose=2, the summary of the failed tests at the top are missing 'FAIL\n'.

for example, this test (in Python 3.7):

```py
import unittest

class TestThing(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_thing1(self):

        for i in range(10):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertLess(i, 10)

    def test_thing2(self):

        for i in range(10):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertLess(i, 9)

    def test_thing3(self):

        for i in range(10):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertLess(i, 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Results in this output:

```
>python .\blah.py

    test_thing1 (__main__.TestThing) ... ok
    test_thing2 (__main__.TestThing) ... test_thing3 (__main__.TestThing) ... ok

    ======================================================================
    FAIL: test_thing2 (__main__.TestThing) (i=9)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\blah.py", line 16, in test_thing2
        self.assertLess(i, 9)
    AssertionError: 9 not less than 9

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I remove the `subtest`, then the output becomes:

```
test_thing1 (__main__.TestThing) ... ok
test_thing2 (__main__.TestThing) ... FAIL
test_thing3 (__main__.TestThing) ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: test_thing2 (__main__.TestThing)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\blah.py", line 16, in test_thing2
    self.assertLess(i, 9)
AssertionError: 9 not less than 9

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I've tried using my own `resultclass` but it appears that the `addFailure` doesn't get called for subtests (like it does for regular tests).

```py
class MyTextTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        print('adding a failure')
        super().addFailure(test, err)

        if self.showAll:
            self.stream.writeln("FAIL")

        elif self.dots:
            self.stream.write('F')
            self.stream.flush()

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        print('adding a success')
        super().addSuccess(test)

        if self.showAll:
            self.stream.writeln("ok")

        elif self.dots:
            self.stream.write('.')
            self.stream.flush()
```

Does anyone know how to fix the output for subtest results (using verbose=2)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if I change the `addSubTest` in `TextTestResult`, that does it.

```py
class MyTextTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):

    def addSubTest(self, test, subtest, err):
        super().addSubTest(test, subtest, err)

        if err is not None:
            if not self.stream.getvalue().strip().endswith('FAIL'):
                self.stream.writeln("FAIL")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # unittest.main(verbosity=2)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(None, resultclass=MyTextTestResult, verbosity=2)

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestThing('test_thing1'))
    suite.addTest(TestThing('test_thing2'))
    suite.addTest(TestThing('test_thing3'))

    runner.run(suite)
```

```
test_thing1 (__main__.TestThing) ... ok
test_thing2 (__main__.TestThing) ... FAIL
test_thing3 (__main__.TestThing) ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: test_thing2 (__main__.TestThing) (i=9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\blah.py", line 22, in test_thing2
    self.assertLess(i, 9)
AssertionError: 9 not less than 9

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `TextTestRunner` doesn't print anything (including the newline) for tests unless all subtests succeed.
Instead of not printing anything, the following TestResult will cause the TextTestRunner to print "some subtests weren't successful" (including a newline):

```
class MyTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
  def startTest(self, *args):
    self.current_test_has_subtests = False
    super().startTest(*args)
  
  def addSubTest(self, *args):
    super().addSubTest(*args)
    self.current_test_has_subtests = True

  def stopTest(self, test):
    super().stopTest(test)
    if self.current_test_has_subtests and not self.wasSuccessful():
      print("some subtests weren't successful")
```

To use this, change the `testRunner` in the `unittest.main` call. For example:

```
unittest.main(
  verbosity=2,
  testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2, resultclass=MyTestRunner)
)
```